# how to make an object face forward?

Tags: modeling, objects

I am a beginner at using Blender. I want to know how to make my object face forward like the video tutorial that I tried to follow. The Blender I use is version 3.0.0.

this is what I tried to do:
[image]

this is what i did:
[image]
Here is the link of the tutorial : https://youtu.be/Ea8Xook8eW4&t=2m28s

Comment: You want your object to be centered in the frame of the viewport? You can do so by pressing the tilde key [ ~ ] and selecting "View Selected" from the pie menu.

Comment: You'll need to include a link to the tutorial you're following in your question (including the timestamp) so that we can see what you're talking about. As far as I can see your sphere **is** "facing forward" since you're currently in Front View and the sphere has been rotated 90 degrees on the X axis, but without more context it's impossible to say.

Comment: @JohnEason here it is! https://youtu.be/Ea8Xook8eW4&t=2m28s . Thanks for reminding!

Comment: Hello Nathan, it's not clear what you mean, as John says your object is facing forward

Comment: @NascentSpace i tried it and it worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: @moonboots Yes, after being reminded I should have phrased my question more clearly. What I want is for the object to face forward but also for the object to be centered.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who took the time to help answer my questions!
I'll do a better job of explaining what's wrong when asking and adding necessary information in the future. Thank you everyone!